# Slick slider in react arrow icon get hiding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

I have set up a slick slider in react with images under each section tag. When I click on the arrows icons randomly it was hiding in the slider.

Please look at this code:

```
 let settings = {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 500,
    arrows: true,
    responsive: [
      {
        settings: {
          infinite: false,
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }
    ]
};

return(
let imageSlider =
      array.image.map((review, i) => {
      return (
        <div
          key={`photo${i}`}
        >
          <figure
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `url(${review})`
            }}
          >
          </figure>
        </div>
      );
    });
  return (
    <div className="left-img">
      <Slider
        {...settings}
      >
        {imageSlider}
      </Slider>
    </div>
)
```

Here I was looping the images and appended to the imageSlider variable thereby I was using this imageSlider inside the Slider class. Images are rendered properly but when clicking on arrow icon it was hiding.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer, noted.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement is not very clear, please add screenshots as well so that we can better understand your problem.

for now, try adding following CSS in your global stylesheet, it might help,

```
.slick-arrow {
    -index: 9;
}
```

Comment: Assume there is a slick slider in same div (under each section tag). Whenever i click on the arrow icon it should show the next image in the slider. But when i click the arrow, the next or prev arrow icon gets hidden.